# how to extract grep and cut into a bash array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I tried:

here is content of file.txt

```
some other text
#1.something1=kjfk
#2.something2=dfkjdk
#3.something3=3232
some other text
```

bash script:

```
ids=( `grep "something" file.txt | cut -d'.' -f1` )

for id in "${ids[@]}"; do
  echo $id
done
```

result:

```
(nothing newline...)
(nothing newline...)
(nothing newline...)
```

but all it prints is nothing like newline for every such id found what am i missing?

Comment: It works for me, it prints 3 lines: `#1`, `#2`, and `#3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `grep` and `cut` should be working but you can use `awk` and reduce 2 commands into one:

```
while read -r id;
   echo "$id"
done < <(awk -F '\\.' '/something/{print $1}' file.txt)
```

To populate an array:

```
ids=()
while read -r id;
   ids+=( "$id" )
done < <(awk -F '\\.' '/something/{print $1}' file.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`'s `-o` option to output only the text matched by a regular expression:

```
$ ids=($(grep -Eo '^#[0-9]+' file.txt))
$ echo ${ids[@]}
#1 #2 #3
```

This of course doesn't check for the existence of a period on the line...  If that's important, then you could either expand things with another pipe:

```
$ ids=($(grep -Eo '^#[0-9]+\.something' file.txt | grep -o '^#[0-9]*'))
```

or you could trim the array values after populating the array:

```
$ ids=($(grep -Eo '^#[0-9]+\.something' file.txt))
$ echo ${ids[@]}
#1.something #2.something #3.something
$ for key in "${!ids[@]}"; do ids[key]="${ids[key]%.*}"; done
$ echo ${ids[@]}
#1 #2 #3
```